# Are Context and MainActivity.this different?

Tags: android, dialog, android-context

In MainActivity, `Context` and `MainActivity` are different?

They are exactly `getApplicationContext()` and `MainActivity.this` in Method.

The reason I'm asking this is because i got error because of them.

if these are different, Complier didn't display red line in code.

I thought it was the same until now.

I got this error code.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.writeweight, PID: 24595
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:843)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:95)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:232)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:279)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:702)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:424)
        at com.example.writeweight.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:85)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:4182)
```

And I changed from `getApplicationContext()` to `MainActivity.this` and it worked well.

Code

```
MainActivity.class
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); // HERE
        builder.setTitle("SET");
        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        return true;
    }
```

Tell me please.
Thank you

Comment: Contrast `getApplicationContext()` with `getActivity()` - the second is equivalent to `MainActivity.this` but is better style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getApplicationContext()` (somewhat unsurprisingly) returns the application context, whilst `MainActivity.this` is itself an activity context. Themes associated with your activity will differ from your application. They aren't the same thing.

> if these are different, Complier didn't display red line in code.

You wont see an error, because it's only a `Context` that is requested. I haven't tried it, but you probably could use an `Application` instance so long as you [specify the theme](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AlertDialog?hl=en#AlertDialog(android.content.Context,%20int)) as well by using `new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext(), /* theme res id */)`

However, all the examples in the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#AlertDialog) use an Activity context, so I'd suggest you just go with that.